# How can I make a vertical line change opacity from top to bottom of a line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a line which should change its opacity along the line from one end to another using HTML or CSS or JS. The line should start with less opacity and should end with high opacity or vice versa.

or

The line should start and end with less opacity and should have high opacity in the middle of the line.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, what you need is a gradient line. Here's an example of such a CSS:

```
hr.name-of-your-vertical-line {
  border : 0;
  height : (height)px; /*your own value to suit your content*/
  width : 1px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #color1, #color2, #color3);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #color1, #color2, #color3);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #color1, #color2, #color3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #color1, #color2, #color3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #color1, #color2, #color3);
}
```

You can read more about gradients [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

[Here's a JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/19avkq4w/) you can look at

Comment: Please don't use w3schools. MDN is far more accurate and authoritative: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient